# 3 SSL Domains but fetches only SSL of First Domain

Tags: ssl, web-server

1 linux host on amazon with Apache as webserver and 3 virtual domains configured on it. also SNI is used , also all the 3 domains have SSL installed on them Whenever access any of these domains the browser always fetches SSL certificate of the first domain. why ?

Comment: Your question needs some improvement from you. In it's current state it lacks a lot of information (e.g. error messages, steps you have tried, research you have done). For help, visit the [help center](http://serverfault.com/help) and specifically [how do I ask a good question](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please include your httpd.conf

Comment: apache provides natively SNI; hence MichelZ is totally right asking for your httpd.conf file

Comment: Apache may or may not provide SNI depending on version; the client may or may not use SNI depending on OS, browser or version.

Answer (score 2):

SNI is not universally supported so you can only reliably have one SSL site per IP because virtual domains by host header require access inside the encrypted payload.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, given your little information the only options, that are almost always working are:

1. Get one IP per virtual host

*or*

2. Get a Certificate that includes those 3 Domain names

Because that way you can eliminate the most commont point: *Misconfigured* or *missing* SNI.

Also, please post your **anonymized error log** (usually in */var/log/apache2/error.log*) and the **httpd.conf + included configs**, so that we can provide better answers.
It may me, that SNI is not compiled into your Apache or you are not using *mod_ssl* for the SSL-connections.